# Filter out rows based on dates and flags from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Working with a python pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
Customer | date_transaction_id    | first_flag | dollars
ABC        2015-10-11-123              Y         100
BCD        2015-03-05-872              N         150
BCD        2015-01-01-923              N         -300
ABC        2015-04-04-910              N         -100
ABC        2015-12-12-765              N         -100
```

The above client ABC returned property in April and then bought something in November. In my analysis I need to start counting their first positive transaction as their first transaction with the company. How do I exclude the first transaction for customer ABC? Please note that client BCD is not a new client, so no rows should be excluded.

So how do I exclude transactions with dates before the `first_flag` Y?

First, I get the date out of date_transaction_id and format it to be a date field.

```
df['date'] = df['date_transaction_id'].astype(str).str[:10]
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then I would sort by customer and by date

```
df = df.sort_values(['Customer', 'date'], ascending=[True, False])
```

But now I am stuck, how to delete the rows by client with dates before the `first_flag` is Y. Please note that a client can have one, none or many transactions before the transaction that is marked Y.

This is the output I am looking for:

```
Customer | date       | first_flag | dollars
ABC        2015-10-11      Y         100
ABC        2015-12-12      N         -100
BCD        2015-01-01      N         -300
BCD        2015-03-05      N         150
```

Comment: Notice that you want the oldest date removed although you sorted the date column in descending order...

Comment: Very true - thank you for catching!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df 

  Customer date_transaction_id first_flag  dollars
0      ABC      2015-10-11-123          Y      100
1      BCD      2015-03-05-872          N      150
2      BCD      2015-01-01-923          N     -300
3      ABC      2015-04-04-910          N     -100
4      ABC      2015-12-12-765          N     -100

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_transaction_id']\
                            .astype(str).str[:10], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.sort_values(['Customer', 'date'])\
                            .drop('date_transaction_id', 1)

df 

  Customer first_flag  dollars       date
3      ABC          N     -100 2015-04-04
0      ABC          Y      100 2015-10-11
4      ABC          N     -100 2015-12-12
2      BCD          N     -300 2015-01-01
1      BCD          N      150 2015-03-05
```

---

First replace `first_flag` with integer values.

```
df.first_flag = df.first_flag.replace({'N' : 0, 'Y' : 1})
```

Now, `groupby` on `Customer` and check `cumsum` wrt the `max` of `first_flag`.

```
df = df.groupby('Customer')[['date', 'first_flag', 'dollars']]\
                .apply(lambda x: x[x.first_flag.cumsum() == x.first_flag.max()])\
                .reset_index(level=0)
df
  Customer       date  first_flag  dollars
0      ABC 2015-10-11           1      100
4      ABC 2015-12-12           0     -100
2      BCD 2015-01-01           0     -300
1      BCD 2015-03-05           0      150
```

*Optional*: Replace the integral values with the old `Y`/`N` using

```
df.first_flag = df.first_flag.replace({0 : 'N', 1 : 'Y'})  
df

  Customer       date first_flag  dollars
0      ABC 2015-10-11          Y      100
4      ABC 2015-12-12          N     -100
2      BCD 2015-01-01          N     -300
1      BCD 2015-03-05          N      150
```

Comment: OMG, typo ...T_T

Comment: @Wen LOL ... :p

Comment: Thank you very much - is there a way without having to list all column names in the groupby - df.groupby('Customer')[['date', 'first_flag', 'dollars']]; my raw dataset has about 30 columns; if there is no other way, I will list all 30 in the code; I didn't show all 30 in my example, sincethey are not necessary for this step, but then they will be necessary for my aggregations and KPIs.

Comment: @jeangelj `df.groupby(df.columns.difference(['Customer']))...` :)

Comment: fyi - you don't need the line break "\" for lines contained within parentheses, e.g. `pd.to_datetime(df['date_transaction_id']\ `

Comment: @Alexander Oh yeah.. it's a matter of habit I picked up from Max.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Convert `date_transaction_id` to date timestamp.
df = df.assign(transaction_date=pd.to_datetime(df['date_transaction_id'].str[:10]))

# Find first transaction dates by customer.
first_transactions = (
    df[df['first_flag'] == 'Y']
    .groupby(['Customer'], as_index=False)['transaction_date']
    .min())

# Merge first transaction date to dataframe.
df = df.merge(first_transactions, how='left', on='Customer', suffixes=['', '_first'])

# Filter data and select relevant columns.
>>> (df[df['transaction_date'] >= df['transaction_date_first']]
     .sort_values(['Customer', 'transaction_date'])
     [['Customer', 'transaction_date', 'first_flag', 'dollars']])
  Customer transaction_date first_flag  dollars
0      ABC       2015-10-11          Y      100
4      ABC       2015-12-12          N     -100
2      BCD       2015-01-01          N     -300
1      BCD       2015-03-05          N      150
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your first question of excluding the first transaction of a customer having a flag 'Y':

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['ABC','2015-10-11','Y',100],
                  ['BCD','2015-03-05','N',150],
                  ['BCD','2015-01-01','N',-300],
                  ['ABC','2015-04-04','N',-100],
                  ['ABC','2015-12-12','N', -100]], 
                  columns=['Customer','date', 'first_flag','dollars'])

# Extract the original columns
cols = df.columns

# Create a label column of whether the customer has a 'Y' flag
df['is_new'] = df.groupby('Customer')['first_flag'].transform('max')

# Apply the desired function, ie. dropping the first transaction
# to the matching records, drop index columns in the end

new_customers = (df[df['is_new'] == 'Y']
                 .sort_values(by=['Customer','date'])
                 .groupby('Customer',as_index=False)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1:]).reset_index()
                 [cols])

# Extract the rest
old_customers = df[df['is_new'] != 'Y']

# Concat the transformed and untouched records together
pd.concat([new_customers, old_customers])[cols]
```

Output:

```
Customer | date       | first_flag | dollars
ABC        2015-10-11      Y         100
ABC        2015-12-12      N         -100
BCD        2015-01-01      N         -300
BCD        2015-03-05      N         150
```

Comment: thank you - I need to drop all transactions before the Y flag, not only the first one, so some customers might have only one and others might have many

Answer (score 2):

All presetting is same with cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's answer, in my answer , I using `idxmax`

---

*Presetting*

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date_transaction_id']\
                            .astype(str).str[:10], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df=df.sort_values(['Customer','date']).replace({'N' : 0, 'Y' : 1}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
L=df.groupby('Customer')['first_flag'].apply(lambda x : x.index>=x.idxmax()).apply(list).values.tolist()
import functools
L=functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,L)
df[L]


Out[278]: 
  Customer date_transaction_id  first_flag  dollars       date
1      ABC      2015-10-11-123           1      100 2015-10-11
2      ABC      2015-12-12-765           0     -100 2015-12-12
3      BCD      2015-01-01-923           0     -300 2015-01-01
4      BCD      2015-03-05-872           0      150 2015-03-05
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that operates on each group of a groupby object.

```
def drop_before(obj):
    # Get the date when first_flag == 'Y'
    y_date = obj[obj.first_flag == 'Y'].date
    if not y_date.values:
        # If it doesn't exist, just return the DataFrame
        return obj
    else:
        # Find where your two drop conditions are satisfied
        cond1 = obj.date < y_date[0]
        cond2 = abc.first_flag == 'N'
        to_drop = obj[cond1 & cond2].index
        return obj.drop(to_drop)

res = df.groupby('Customer').apply(drop_before)
res = res.set_index(res.index.get_level_values(1))
print(res)
  Customer date_transaction_id first_flag  dollars       date
4      ABC      2015-12-12-765          N     -100 2015-12-12
0      ABC      2015-10-11-123          Y      100 2015-10-11
1      BCD      2015-03-05-872          N      150 2015-03-05
2      BCD      2015-01-01-923          N     -300 2015-01-01
```

So picture separate DataFrames for each *group* of customers (1 for ABC, 1 for BCD).  Then when you use `apply`, `drop_before` is applied to each sub-frame and they are then recombined.

This assumes you only have a max of one `first_flag == 'Y'` per Customer.  That seems to be the case in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @Brad; I am trying this option right now - I have quite a large dataset and it is still running